# Modifying classList in event handler in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I am trying to achieve with this is quite simple. I have an array of options/tags displayed in a div. I want the classes to change on click to simulate an "active" state. While I've seen a few snippets on codesandbox that I could use to achieve what I want, my curiosity still is why this wouldn't even trigger the class change.

The referenced event elements and id match...

```
const variantHandler = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  
const d = e.currentTarget

const c = () => {
    variants.map((variant: any) => {
        if (d.id !== variant.node.id) {
            d.classList.remove('bg-gray-900', 'text-myGray', 'dark:bg-myGray', 'dark:text-gray-900')
            //alert('reached remove')
        }
        else {
            d.classList.add('bg-gray-900', 'text-myGray', 'dark:bg-myGray', 'dark:text-gray-900')
            //alert('reached add')
        }
    })
}
c();
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using direct DOM modification like this in a React component, that being said are you setting an id on the element? and are you sure the currentTarget is the element you expect?

Comment: Variable names like e, d, c are a shot in the foot. Naming well your variables goes a long way into avoid creating many many bugs

Comment: Thanks for your swift response @pilchard I understand why I do not need to manipulate the DOM directly like this. I usually don't.  I do stuff like this 

<button className={` ${isDisabled ? 'opacity-50' : ''} flex h-8 w-10 border`} onClick={decreaseQuantity} disabled={isDisabled}> 

And Yes to both your questions.

Comment: @DanielCruz I'll definitely rename/refactor my code.

Comment: You'll need to provide more context, the snippet is awkward but should be working. Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or link to one for more help.

Comment: Did you inspect the elements with devtools to see if the changes are applied? It could be that they're being applied but the page isn't reflecting it

Comment: It could be because the event object is wrapped by a SyntheticEvent in react, and that wrapper object is preventing you from altering the dom pragmatically. You might wanna look into it https://ryankubik.com/blog/dont-mix-react-synthetic-and-native-events

Comment: @shidoro from the devtools, the classes aren't applied. However, the alerts are triggered when I uncomment them.